# Update json field in postgres

Tags: postgresql, golang, gorm

Пользуюсь ORM GORM для работы с бд postgresql.

В таблице одно из полей содержит объект json и тип, в рамках postgres, у этого поля соответствующий - json.

Сейчас мне требуется обновить только часть этого объекта. Например json: `{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"}` и я хочу поменять только `key2`  установив ему значение `value5` например.

Можно ли это делать с помощью GORM? И если да, то как это делается?

Я знаю, что можно достать весь объект, распаковать json в структуру, поменять нужно поле, запаковать обратно и положить обратно в таблицу. Но выглядит это довольно громоздко. Смотрел в доках GORM  и что-то не разобрался можно ли с его помощью такое провернуть.

Comment: Пакет [go-gorm/datatypes](https://github.com/go-gorm/datatypes). Умеет искать по ключам, обновлять отдельные ключи

Answer (score 1):

Необязательно полностью распаковывать объект и упаковывать обратно.

```
type YourModel struct {
    ID   uint
    JSON json.RawMessage `gorm:"column:__json_column__"`
}
```

Сейчас нет возможности проверить, попробуй так:

```
func UpdateKey() {
    var yourModel YourModel
    db.Model(&yourModel).Where("id = ?", __ID__).UpdateColumn("json", gorm.Expr("jsonb_set(json, '{key2}', ?::jsonb)", `{"key2": "value5"}`))
}
```

**json_column** - название столбца, где лежит json.

**ID** - Id записи

**UPDATE**: Изменил функцию UpdateKey, чтобы принимала параметр:

```
func UpdateKey(value string) {
    var yourModel YourModel
    db.Model(&yourModel).Where("id = ?", __ID__).UpdateColumn("json", gorm.Expr("jsonb_set(json, '{key2}', ?::jsonb)", fmt.Sprintf(`{"key2": "%s"}`, value)))
}
```

Comment: А как в эту строку добавить переменную из кода? знак вопроса, полагаю здесь уже не сработает? Нужно чтобы key2 взялось из переменной и value5 тоже

Comment: Добавил изменённую функцию в ответе выше.